# What is the value of examinations (as compared with homework/term papers) under the honour system?

Tags: exams, homework

This question is asked in a university context where one assumes that the honour system works. (It is obvious that one needs more elaborate "sit-in" examination systems if students try to *game* the system and do not complete the assigned tasks themselves.)

What is the value that "sit-in" examinations *add* to that of evaluating homework and/or term papers?

The latter appear to be more reflective of the kind of situation where the student will apply what is learned in the classroom, which is to formulate an answer (on their own) to the query *with* access to various resources such as books, the internet and discussions with others. Moreover, h/w and term papers can (and usually do) have deadlines too!

Hence, why are examinations conducted at all in such a context? Perhaps, in some cases, examinations are treated just like homework with additional weight?

**Update**: To clarify the notion of "examinations" as contrasted with the other forms, what is particularly questionable about examinations is the issue of limitations on time and access to source materials. There are few "real life" tasks that one needs to train for where such limitations are critical.

Comment: Do you have in mind driver education or functional analysis?  As it stands, this is way to broad to answer.

Comment: @TerryLoring Thanks for the query. Clarified.

Comment: Are you asking about take-home tests?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Take home examinations are essentially homework/term papers by a different name. The question is about "sit in" examinations.

Comment: It is? I'm confused then.

Comment: @kapil Take home exams are not the same as homework/term papers. Take home exams administered by an institution with a functional honor system can have limitations on time and external materials, e.g. "the exam will be 3 hours, closed-book, take-home." Homework and term papers usually allow research and looking at books and notes.

Comment: @shoover The time limitation would then bother me. There are very few real life tasks that need such strict time limitations. Similarly, not being allowed to consult material is also problematic. Such "take-home" examinations would also be questionable, therefore.

Comment: @Kapil I'm just giving you my personal experience at a university with an honor system that functions that way. The take-home exams were treated the same as in-person exams with the major difference that students had the freedom to choose when and where to take them. This freedom extended to semester final exams as well.

Answer (score 3):

Exam situations have the added safety of other students watching each other, whereas homework has only the one student alone responsible for their own honesty. Security relies on redundancy.